# Logical fallacy in conjonction statement. How to find?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have a scenario from which I have to represent it in propositions:

> In City A, a resident is not allowed to have more than 3 dogs and more than 3 cats. Resident A has 5 dogs but no cat, has he violated the regulation?

This is what the professor did on the Powerpoint:
$$p: \text{A citizen has no more than 3 dogs}  \\q: \text{A citizen has no more than 3 cats}$$
Regulation is considered violated if the proposition is False.
So for Citizen A, the proposition would be : $$p \wedge q = T \wedge F = F \ \text{(Regulation Violated)}$$

However, this is what I did base on my comprehension of this question:
$$p: \text{A citizen has more than 3 dogs}  \\q: \text{A citizen has  more than 3 cats}$$
Regulation is considered violated if the proposition is True.
So for Citizen A, the proposition would be : $$p \wedge q = T \wedge F = F \ \text{(Regulation Not Violated)}$$

So both of these two ways of interpreting the scenario seems logical, but we have totally different answer. So I want to know where have I made an error with logic? It can get really confusing sometimes.

Comment: Your professor is a dum-dum

Comment: But why is he wrong?? Where is the mistake?

Comment: In the Professor's method, Regulation should be $P$ or $Q$, not $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: That is what I think also. But is there any formal way to prove that he is wrong? For my side, I find that his method is a negation of my statement $$ \neg p \wedge \neg q = \neg (p \vee q) $$ but it still doesn't seem to equal to the right method of his way since it should be $$ p \vee q $$

Comment: Yeah there's definitely a formal way using DeMorgan's laws but I haven't learnt propositional logic yet so idk lol. Someone else take over.

Comment: Oh lol turns out I was wrong hmm

Comment: Haha it is fine. I just started learning Discrete Math and it is giving me headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the professor has done is stated what a citizen needs to do to stay within the law $(1)$. As such, citizens need to obey all of the regulations to stay within the law $(2)$.

\begin{align}\tag{1}
p:&\text{ A citizen has no more than 3 dogs}\\
q:&\text{ A citizen has no more than 3 cats}
\end{align}
\begin{align}\tag{2}
p\land q
\end{align}

What you have done is show what they need to do to break it $(3)$. A citizen breaks the law when they violate any of the regulations $(4)$, and it is not a requirement to violate all of them.

\begin{align}\tag{3}
p:&\text{ A citizen has more than 3 dogs}\\
q:&\text{ A citizen has more than 3 cats}
\end{align}
\begin{align}\tag{4}
p\lor q
\end{align}

Your error was using a logical AND between $p$ and $q$ in your comprehension of the question instead of a logical OR.

Comment: Oh okay because I interpreted the word "and" as the logical AND.

Comment: Why would the word "and" not mean logical AND? If in that case: "A resident is not allowed to have more than 3 dogs and more than 3 cats" = "A resident is not allowed to have more than 3 dogs or more than 3 cats"? In the context of propositional logic, this question is poorly written.